# Rails hash combine by their value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `questions` list, and I need to separate them. The relationship is

```
Question_set has_many questions
BookVolume has_many questions
Subject has_many  book_volumes
Publisher has_many subjects
Section has_many :questions
```

Now I only put `questions` and their relative model `id`, `name` into `hash` inside an `array`.

```
data = []
question_set.questions.each do |q|
    data << {publisher: {id: q.publisher.id, name: q.publisher.name}, subject: {id: q.book_volume.subject.id, name: q.book_volume.subject.name}, volume: {id: q.book_volume_id, name: q.book_volume.name}, chapter: [{id: q.section_id, name: q.section.name}]}  
end
```

Therefore, the `data` basically will be

```
>>data

[
    {
        :publisher => {
              :id => 96,
            :name => "P1"
        },
          :subject => {
              :id => 233,
            :name => "S1"
        },
           :volume => {
              :id => 1136,
            :name => "V1"
        },
          :chapter => [
            {
                  :id => 16155,
                :name => "C1"
            }
        ]
    },
       {
        :publisher => {
              :id => 96,
            :name => "P1"
        },
          :subject => {
              :id => 233,
            :name => "S1"
        },
           :volume => {
              :id => 1136,
            :name => "V1"
        },
          :chapter => [
            {
                  :id => 16158,
                :name => "C2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

However, I want the `chapter` to be combined if they got the same `publisher`, `subject` and `volume`
So, in this case, it will be

```
>>data 

[
    {
        :publisher => {
              :id => 96,
            :name => "P1"
        },
          :subject => {
              :id => 233,
            :name => "S1"
        },
           :volume => {
              :id => 1136,
            :name => "V1"
        },
          :chapter => [
            {
                  :id => 16155,
                :name => "C2"
            },
            {
                  :id => 16158,
                :name => "C2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
def group_em(data)
  data.group_by { |h| [h[:publisher], h[:subject], h[:volume]] }.
       map do |k,v|
         h = { publisher: k[0], subject: k[1], volume: k[2] }
         h.update(chapters: v.each_with_object([]) { |f,a|
           a << f[:chapter] }.flatten)
       end
end
```

**Example**

Let `data` equal the array of hashes (the first array above).

```
group_em(data)
  #=> [{:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"},
  #     :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #     :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"},
  #     :chapters=>[{:id=>16155, :name=>"C1"}, {:id=>16158, :name=>"C2"}]
  #    } 
  #   ]
```

Here `data` contains only two hashes and those hashes have the same values for the keys `:publisher`, `:subject` and `:volume`. This code allows the array to have any number of hashes, and will group them by an array of the values of those three keys, producing one hash for each of those groups. Moreover, the values of the key `:chapters` are arrays containing a single hash, but this code permits that array to contain multiple hashes. (If that array will always have exactly one hash, consider making the value of `:chapters` the hash itself rather than an array containing that hash.)

**Explanation**

See [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`).

The steps are as follows.

```
h = data.group_by { |h| [h[:publisher], h[:subject], h[:volume]] }
  #=> {
  #    [{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"},
  #     {:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #     {:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"}
  #    ]=>[{:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"},
  #         :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #         :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"},
  #         :chapter=>[{:id=>16155, :name=>"C1"}]
  #        },
  #        {:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"},
  #         :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #         :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"},
  #         :chapter=>[{:id=>16158, :name=>"C2"}]
  #        }
  #       ]
  #   }
```

The first key-value pair is passed to `map`'s block and the block variables are assigned.

```
k,v = h.first
  #=> [[{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"}, {:id=>233, :name=>"S1"}, {:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"}],
  #   [{:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"}, :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #     :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"}, :chapter=>[{:id=>16155, :name=>"C1"}]},
  #    {:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"}, :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #     :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"}, :chapter=>[{:id=>16158, :name=>"C2"}]}]]
k #=> [{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"}, {:id=>233, :name=>"S1"}, {:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"}]
v #=> [{:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"},
  #     :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #     :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"},
  #     :chapter=>[{:id=>16155, :name=>"C1"}]},
  #    {:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"},
  #     :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #     :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"},
  #     :chapter=>[{:id=>16158, :name=>"C2"}]}]
```

and the block calculation is performed.

```
h = { publisher: k[0], subject: k[1], volume: k[2] }
  #=> {:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"},
  #    :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #    :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"}
  #   } 
a = v.each_with_object([]) { |f,a| a << f[:chapter] }
  #=> [[{:id=>16155, :name=>"C1"}], [{:id=>16158, :name=>"C2"}]] 
b = a.flatten
  #=> [{:id=>16155, :name=>"C1"}, {:id=>16158, :name=>"C2"}]
h.update(chapters: b)
  #=> {:publisher=>{:id=>96, :name=>"P1"},
  #    :subject=>{:id=>233, :name=>"S1"},
  #    :volume=>{:id=>1136, :name=>"V1"},
  #    :chapters=>[{:id=>16155, :name=>"C1"}, {:id=>16158, :name=>"C2"}]
  #   }
```

[Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) could be used in place of `Hash#update`.

Comment: I'm not sure about you said `Letting arr equal the array of hashes (the first array above), we can do the following.` Does it mean `arr = data`?

Comment: If the variable `data` holds that array, yes. When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `data = [{ :publisher=>...]`). That way, readers can refer to those variable (here just `data`) in comments and answers without having to define them. You might edit your question to do that.

Comment: I did define the variable name `data = []`, and put `hash` into it in my question, did you mean this?

Comment: I see. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful for me!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    data = {}

    question_set.questions.each do |q|
      key = "#{q.publisher.id}:#{q.book_volume.subject.id}:#{q.book_volume_id}"
      if data[key].present?
        data[key][:chapter] << {id: q.section_id, name: q.section.name}
      else
        data[key] = {publisher: {id: q.publisher.id, name: q.publisher.name}, subject: {id: q.book_volume.subject.id, name: q.book_volume.subject.name}, volume: {id: q.book_volume_id, name: q.book_volume.name}, chapter: [{id: q.section_id, name: q.section.name}]}  
      end
    end

    result = data.values
```

use the combination of publisher'id, subject'id and volume'id as a unique key to combine your data.

Comment: At the last line, result = data.values, it becomes a array.

Comment: Oh, I miss it, it's really amazing approach!